# How can I prevent 'duplicate' JSON entries from being inserted into a table

Tags: json, sql-server

I have some JSON from a care home management system. Two objects from the JSON in question are below:

```
[{"Location":"Home 1","Community":"Ground Floor","FirstName":"Resident 1","PreferredName":"Res","LastName":"ResName","Gender":"Female","DateOfBirth":"1929-01-19T00:00:00","NINumber":null,"NHSNumber":"1234567890","FileOpened":"2019-10-18T00:00:00","Room":"B2","ExternalReference":"","RisksToBeAwareOf":"I am very hard of hearing and have vascular dementia which can cause me to have short term memory loss, however i am normally lucid and able to make my own choices and decisions.","PersonID":"5654689568973897589345","ConnectionID":"834895934t89f87438957","LocationID":"7187f0ac-b8f2-4f06-87ba-472aff3afa5e","CommunityID":"bdaf4054-8efa-4dac-ae40-52272a9001d1"},{"Location":"Home 1","Community":"Residents","FirstName":"Resident 1","PreferredName":"Res","LastName":"ResName","Gender":"Female","DateOfBirth":"1929-01-19T00:00:00","NINumber":null,"NHSNumber":"1234567890","FileOpened":"2019-10-18T00:00:00","Room":"B2","ExternalReference":"","RisksToBeAwareOf":"I am very hard of hearing and have vascular dementia which can cause me to have short term memory loss, however i am normally lucid and able to make my own choices and decisions.","PersonID":"5654689568973897589345","ConnectionID":"834895934t89f87438957","LocationID":"7187f0ac-b8f2-4f06-87ba-472aff3afa5e","CommunityID":"bdaf4054-8efa-4dac-ae40-52272a9001d1"}]
```

You will see that it has Location AND Community, which refers to the home and also the floor / unit that resident is on. I have deliberately changed the names and details of the resident in this example, but you will note they are both the same record, but one is in location "Ground Floor", and the other is in "Residents". Due to the way the system assigns people to communities, it's possible to have the same resident in more than one grouping (for things such as seeing information about ALL residents at once, or sub-grouping residents who are on multiple floors / areas, but are perhaps nursing, or bed-bound residents.

This creates the problem, and the JSON export cannot control this, that the exported JSON simply dumps all of this information at once. Since all the information apart from Community is repeated, this is effectively duplicated information.

I thought I could counter this by using the following code within the import SP in SQL Server:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu 
on cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
where 
tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
and tc.TABLE_NAME = 'Residents'
and cu.COLUMN_NAME like '%LastName%') = 0  
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [Residents] ADD CONSTRAINT U_NAME_Residents UNIQUE(FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, ConnectionID, PersonID); 
END
```

This isn't working correctly. Not only do I keep getting records for Ground Floor and Residents, but it isn't even currently stopping repeats of both of those records. Strangely, this bit of code does seem to work in other tables and SPs I've made.

So, in a very long-winded explanation, other than simply writing a delete from [Residents] where community = *the one I don't want*, I would like either:

- a trigger that prevents duplicates of records with the same FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, ConnectionID and PersonID
- or a way of ignoring the JSON for the communities I wish to exclude.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to impose constraints *inside* a JSON string, you shouldn't be using a JSON string in the first place. It means you're using JSON to stuff relational data into a single field instead of creating a proper table with columns. IN the relational model, if you want to query something, it has to be on a column, even if it's a computed column

Comment: `UNIQUE` works fine. If you create a UNIQUE constraint that covers the JSON field, it will ensure no two rows have the same string in that field. If you add multiple fields, it will ensure no two rows have the same value combinations. The constraint you posted here doesn't seem to include any JSON though, just names and ID fields

Comment: In fact, that UNIQUE constraint is suspicious it says it's *fine* to have multiple names and dates for the same PersonID/ConnectionID combination

Comment: Thanks. The parts of the SP I didn't include here create and / or insert into a proper table with columns. That is why I say "other than simply writing a delete from [Residents where community =..." I just want a more efficient and, preferably, pre-emptive way in which to spot those duplicates of most fields and stop them being entered. I do feel the need to always say this: I am not a software developer by trade. I am creating all of this by myself, learning as I go along. Be gentle with me lol.

Comment: All the more reason to *not* use JSON this way. It's neither simpler nor easier. Use proper tables with proper columns and foreign keys. Different entities go into different tables. If you care about locations, communities and residents, those should all be separate tables. The attributes of those entities become columns in the tables

Comment: Thank you for your 'help'. I will try and figure it out by myself.

Comment: In the end, I realised I could just add a where clause: WHERE Community = ''Residents'' at the end of the JSON SQL code.

Comment: There's no JSON SQL code in this question. What you did though *is* pulling the values out of the JSON. You can create a computed column with the JSON expression and turn `Community` into a column that can be indexed and constrained. If you posted the actual table schema, or at least the name of the JSON column, people could post the correct expression for this

Comment: BTW you should also change that JSON to an object instead of an array. Right now, that string can contain multiple `Community` values. Which one are you using in `: WHERE Community = ''Residents''` ? The first, last, or middle one?

Comment: I didn't include it because I didn't think it was relevant. I was asking about creating constraints on the data that's imported. I guess I should've realised I could add the constraint within the parsing, but like I've said already, I'm new to this and learning as I go.

Comment: This isn't about being new or learning. It may look like it's clear to you, but other people can't understand what you're talking about - is this a single field value? Or an input string you want to split and insert into a table? If you post the schema, query and expected results people could understand what's going on even if the rest of the question is in ancient Egyptian.

Answer (score -1):

WHERE Community = ''Residents'' at the end of the JSON parsing.